# How to query count difference value in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have in, out data in one column. I don't know how to count who don't have out value.

Database structure [image]

I have used this query doesn't work.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[SevenLocation] t1 LEFT JOIN (select SN from [dbo].[SevenLocation] where TypeScan = 'Out')t2 ON t2.SN = t1.SN WHERE t2.SN IS NULL
```

The result should be 2 from count query.

Comment: why 2? As I understand `SN` is something unique. And you need to count amount of `SN` where no records are present with `OUT` value. Is it right?

Comment: Ok I will describe this problem. This application track in and out value that come into some location which everybody can access any number of times. mean when 1000255863 have in value and out value equal zero people in room but if 1000255863 come to room again system should count be 1

Comment: but is it possible to have for the same client `IN` and `IN` in a row? I mean logically it should be `In and Out`, but can be something like `IN and IN`? Then is it enough of one `OUT` for these 2 `INs` ?

Comment: Oh You're right. It's my mistake. What should i do? or redesign database structure.

Comment: it was a question only :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the analytical function lead as follows:

```
select count(case when type = 'In' and ld_type is null then 1 end) as cnt
(select t.*,
       lead(type_scan) over (partition by SN, date_scan order by time_scan) as ld_type
  from your_table t) t
```

Comment: Check now!! You must have not used the table name with alias. I have explicitly mentioned the table name as your_Table, replace it with your original table name

Comment: Great ! sorry my mistake. i try to use with cte table and it works. this is solution for me,

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[SevenLocation] where TypeScan <> 'Out'`